# Problem with LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a problem when executing the JavaScript of my LWC.
It is a button that performs a download of a document, but the `recordId` never passes it so it does not fill in the values that I already have registered.
Any idea what it could be?

This is part of the JS, it does not retrieve the data.
Thanks

```js
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import downloadDocumentFromAzureRelay from '@salesforce/apex/AzureHybridRelay.downloadDocumentFromAzureRelay';

const FIELDS = [
    'OrderDocument_Attach__c.TXT_idDocument__c',
    'OrderDocument_Attach__c.TXT_FileName__c',
    'OrderDocument_Attach__c.OrderId__c'    
];

 const COLUMNS = [
     {label: 'ID del Documento', fieldName: 'TXT_idDocument__c', type:'text'},
     {label: 'Nombre del Documento', fieldName: 'TXT_FileName__c', type:'text'},
     {label: 'ID de la Orden', fieldName:'OrderId__c', type:'text'}
 ];
export default class DownloadDocumentsLWC extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;

    data = [];
    columns = COLUMNS;

    idDocument;    
    documentName;    
    OrderId;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
    loadRecord({ error, data }) {
        console.log('entro al loadRecord');
        if (data) {
            console.log('data');
            console.log(data);
            this.idDocument = data.fields.TXT_idDocument__c;
            this.documentName = data.fields.TXT_FileName__c;
            this.OrderId = data.fields.OrderId__c;
            this.data = [
                {
                    TXT_idDocument__c: this.idDocument,
                    TXT_FileName__c: this.documentName,
                    OrderId__c: this.OrderId
                }

            ];
        } else if (error) {
            console.error('Error loading record:', error);
        }
    }
downloadDocument(){
        if(!this.idDocument || !this.documentName || !this.orderId){
            console.error('No se ha podido recuperar los valores de IdDOcument, DocumentName y OrderId');
            return;    
        }
        downloadDocumentFromAzureRelay({
            idDocument: this.idDocument,
            documentName: this.documentName,
            OrderId: this.orderId
        })
        .then(result => {
            this.downloadBlobAsFile(result, this.documentName);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error fetching document:', error.message);
        });
    }
```

XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>57.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
            <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
            <objects>
                <object>OrderDocument_Attach__c</object>
            </objects>                                    
        </targetConfig>
        <!-- <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <objects>
                <object>OrderDocument_Attach__c</object>
            </objects>
        </targetConfig>                 -->
    </targetConfigs>        
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-quick-action-panel header="Order Document Attrach">
    <!-- <lightning-card title="Order Document Attach">                 -->
        <lightning-datatable
            key-field="TXT_idDocument__c"
            data={data}
            columns={columns}>
        </lightning-datatable>               
         <lightning-button label="Descargar Documento" onclick={downloadDocument} class="slds-m-top_medium"></lightning-button>
    <!-- </lightning-card>     -->
    </lightning-quick-action-panel>  
</template>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe you should use double quotation marks (") instead of single ones when referencing $recordId.

Comment: @user1067017 I have changed it but it still does not work.
Is it something to do with HTML or XML?
<apiVersion>57.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <property name="recordId" label="Record ID" type="String" />
        </targetConfig>        
    </targetConfigs>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the `recordId` property from the XML file. If a component  is used on a Lightning record page and you defined a `recordId` property decorated with `@api`, the [framework automatically sets it](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-record-context.html). Problably it has been overwritten in the Lightning builder.

Moreover to [configure a component for quick action](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-config-for-quick-actions.html), just a `lightning__RecordAction` element is not enough, you need also a `targetConfig` with an `actionType` element.
Since you need a screen action you have to add the following lines to your XML:

```xml
<targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
    <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
</targetConfig>
```

You can also remove both target and targetConfig elements related to `lightning__RecordPage`.

The XML file should look like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>58.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
            <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Keep in mind that a wire adapter is called the first time right after the constructor (and before the connected callback), so that time `recordId` would be still `undefined`, and it provisions an empty object. Then, once `recordId` is setted, it's called again due to [reactive variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/data-wire-service-about.html). This time it will provision the actual data.

> We call the wire service reactive in part because it supports reactive variables, which are prefixed with `$`. If a reactive variable changes, the wire service provisions new data

That's why you need both `if (data)` and `else if (error)` (the first time you get no `data`).

For the same reason I would change `data = [];` to `data;` in the JS, then I would add a `lwc:if` directive to the quick-action-panel:

```html
<lightning-quick-action-panel header="Order Document Attrach" lwc:if={data}>
```

This way it will be rendered only once the `getRecord` provisions the data.

By the way, it doesn't matter if you use single or double quote for string, both are valid options, just be consistent.

Keep in mind that wire adapters provided by `lightning/ui*Api` modules enforce FLS and sharing settings, so be sure to have read access to those fields and Order object.
[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/data-ui-api.html)

> Lightning Data Service is built on top of User Interface API. [...]
> UI API responses also respect CRUD access, field-level security settings, and sharing settings. This means that the framework displays only records and fields for which users have CRUD access and FLS visibility. You get all these features by using the Lightning Data Service wire adapters (lightning/ui*Api) and the components built on it.

Instead of hardcoding *ObjectApiName.FieldApiName* in the `FIELDS` array, you could [import reference to fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/apex-schema.html):

> If you import references to objects and fields, Salesforce verifies that the objects and fields exist (**which also catches typos**), prevents objects and fields from being deleted, and cascades any renamed objects and fields into your component's source code. It also ensures that dependent objects and fields are included in change sets and packages.

Moreover, this way you could leverage [`getFieldValue`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-get-field-value.html).

JS

```js
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import downloadDocumentFromAzureRelay from '@salesforce/apex/AzureHybridRelay.downloadDocumentFromAzureRelay';

import ID_DOCUMENT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/OrderDocument_Attach__c.TXT_idDocument__c';
import FILE_NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/OrderDocument_Attach__c.TXT_FileName__c';
import ORDER_ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/OrderDocument_Attach__c.OrderId__c';

const FIELDS = [
    ID_DOCUMENT_FIELD,
    FILE_NAME_FIELD,
    ORDER_ID_FIELD  
];

const COLUMNS = [
    { label: 'ID del Documento', fieldName: 'documentId' },
    { label: 'Nombre del Documento', fieldName: 'documentName' },
    { label: 'ID de la Orden', fieldName: 'orderId' }
];

export default class DownloadDocumentsLWC extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;

    data;
    columns = COLUMNS;

    idDocument;
    documentName;
    OrderId;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
    loadRecord({ error, data }) {
        console.log('entro al loadRecord');
        if (data) {
            console.log('data');
            console.log(data);
            this.idDocument = getFieldValue(data, ID_DOCUMENT_FIELD);
            this.documentName = getFieldValue(data, FILE_NAME_FIELD);
            this.OrderId = getFieldValue(data, ORDER_ID_FIELD);
            this.data = [
                {
                    documentId: this.idDocument,
                    documentName: this.documentName,
                    orderId: this.OrderId
                }
            ];
        } else if (error) {
            console.error('Error loading record:', error);
        }
    }

    downloadDocument(){
        if(!this.idDocument || !this.documentName || !this.orderId){
            console.error('No se ha podido recuperar los valores de IdDOcument, DocumentName y OrderId');
            return; 
        }
        downloadDocumentFromAzureRelay({
            idDocument: this.idDocument,
            documentName: this.documentName,
            OrderId: this.orderId
        })
        .then(result => {
            this.downloadBlobAsFile(result, this.documentName);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error fetching document:', error.message);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I have tried to change the XML as you indicated but it still does not work, it does not retrieve the Id, so the rest of the values are not retrieved.
In the XML I had to add <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>, because otherwise it did not appear in the dropdown to create a new action as LWC.

Comment: XML:
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>57.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">            
            <objects>
                <object>OrderDocument_Attach__c</object>
            </objects>
        </targetConfig>                
    </targetConfigs>        
</LightningComponentBundle>

Comment: @user138402 Where this component is used? Is it used as only as a quick action? If so, is it a screen action or an headless one? Is this quick action on the record page of `OrderDocument_Attach__c` object?

Comment: It is a custom object (OrderDocument_Attach__c), it is not used in any page. Inside the object is where the new action is created as a lighting web component.

Comment: @user138402 Could you please edit the question adding the HTML code? How did you check that `this.recordId` is blank?

Comment: I have added the HTML in the post. I have performed a DEBUG of the JS in the browser and the error returned (a controlled error in the JS) is that it was not able to retrieve the recordId.

Comment: The OrderId field is a Lookup of the Order object, I don't know if this can affect it.

Comment: @user138402 I updated the answer. Could you please post the error message verbatim?

Comment: The error is in the JS part
 downloadDocument(){
        if(!this.idDocument || !this.documentName || !this.orderId){
            console.error('Could not retrieve the values of IdDOcument, DocumentName and OrderId');
            return;    
        }

Comment: @user138402 did you try the `lwc:if` on lightning-quick-action-panel after changing the JS? When you click on the download button, is there a value in each column? You shouldn't click on it if a cell is blank. If a cell is blank, please check FLS and CRUD permissions.

Comment: Yes, i try the lwc:if {data} and XML.
I have attached an image in the Post.
That is the object with the completed data, on the right side in the dropdown is the button "Download" when you click it a PopUp is shown (the html of the LWC) with three columns (IdDocument, DocumentName and OrderId) with a check to select it and the button "Download Document". I believe that as now it calls directly to the IF that the HTML does not show it.

Comment: @user138402 since the table is still hidden after few seconds you opened the modal, it means that the data hasn't been loaded. Maybe there's a typo in a field ApiName. Importing the references of the fields would catch such typos. I updated the answer adding an example. Let me know. By the way, do you see the `console.log('data');` in the browser console?

Comment: With the last modification it works, it already recovers the values of the fields, now I have a small problem and it is that the pdf is downloaded but with an error when opening it.
Thanks

Comment: @user138402 I'm glad I could help. Please consider to mark helpful answers provided to your questions as accepted, to benefit the whole community. [Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) you can read why this is a good practice.